# How could I receive the return value of one function into another function in java

Tags: java, function, class, parameters, return-value

```
class Abc
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    }

    public double[] set(double new_x, double new_y)
    {
        //body

        return new double[]{x,y};
    }

    public double set2(double g, double x, double y) //This x and y are the same x and y return by function set
    {
        //body

        return goal;
    }
}
```

My program is that I want to receive the same value in `set2`'s argument(parameter) that return by `set` function. As you can see that `set` function return an array which consist of two variable x and y. This x and y value is received by `set2` function in it's function argument section. How is it possible?

Comment: This code won't compile. `new_y` is missing a type

Comment: This sort of requirement is best covered by streams.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
double[] setResult = set(new_x, new_y);
set2(g, setResult[0], setResult[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might helpful to you:

```
public class Abc {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double arrayOfDoubles[] = set(6,55);
    set2(2, arrayOfDoubles[0], arrayOfDoubles[1]);

}

public static double[] set(double new_x, double new_y) {
    //body
    double x = new_x;
    double y = new_y;
    //do what ever you want
    return new double[]{x,y};
}

public static double set2(double g, double x, double y) {
    //body
    double goal = g;
    //do what ever you want
    return goal;
}
}
```

The way the program runs:(step by step)

In main function:

1.assign the resultant values of set() funtion to a arrayOfDoubles variable.

2.call the set2() function by passing the parameters g, arrayOfDoubles[0], arrayOfDoubles[1].